# API for Giving Notification when a file is added or deleted in a folder

Tags: c++, visual-c++

is there any windows API or shell API which will give a notification on when a file is added or deleted in a folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These API's can help you. and you can find a nice tutorial [here](http://www.relisoft.com/win32/watcher.html)

[FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[FindCloseChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364414%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[FindNextChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364427%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx) will notify you when something changes.

[ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx) can give you the exact details of what changed.

Answer (score 3):

See [Directory Management Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363950(VS.85).aspx), more specifically `FindFirstChangeNotification`.

Answer (score 1):

The [FindFirstChangeNotification Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) is already mentioned.  In case you need something more than the win32 API, here is a very good project for watching folders:

[CDirectoryChangeWatcher - ReadDirectoryChangesW all wrapped up](http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorychangewatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Win32 API provides the [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx) function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Those API won't help you in case you're monitoring some file on the network share or removable drive. In case share is disconnected or flash drive ejected - no notification.